# Не работает NodePath при вставке в массив с редактора

Tags: c#, godot

Вот такой вот Dictationary на картинке, я его оббегаю в цикле:

```cs
if (traps != null && traps.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var indTrap in traps)
    {
        NodePath trap = indTrap as NodePath;
        GD.Print("trap.ToString()="+trap.ToString() + "trap.GetConcatenatedSubnames()=" 
                 + trap.GetConcatenatedSubnames() + "|trap.GetAsPropertyPath().ToString()="+trap.GetAsPropertyPath().ToString() + 
                 "|trap.GetName()="+trap.GetName(0));
        RigidBody2D rbTrap = GetNode<RigidBody2D>(trap);
        if (rbTrap != null)
        {
            CollisionShape2D cshape = rbTrap.GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D");
            cshape.Disabled = isOpen;
        }
    }
}
```

Все хорошо только вот `RigidBody2D rbTrap` стабильно равен null. Вот кстати что выводит `GD.Print`:

```
trap.ToString()=../Trap_3trap.GetConcatenatedSubnames()=|trap.GetAsPropertyPath().ToString()=:../Trap_3|trap.GetName()=..
```

Почему? Должно же работать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поправьте код, он кажется поврежден при вставке

Comment: Да квадратики откуда то взялись, я поправил, правда не думаю что поможет.